# Intellij IDEA not displaying src folder in project

Tags: intellij-idea

[Project folder is not displaying src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkYCL.png)

[That's how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp2BJ.png)

It originally looked like image #2, somehow it became image #1, and I can't access my source files. How do I change it back?

Comment: Make sure the project has been opened as Gradle project: use File | New | Project from Existing Sources... action and select main Gradle build file to import from. Does it help?

Comment: No I'm afraid it's the same result.  I opened using existing sources and I opened built.gradle.kts.  The project successfully opened but it still won't show my src.

Comment: Do you see Gradle tool window (View | Tool Windows | Gradle)? Make sure **Gradle** plugin is enabled. Please provide a sample project if issue remains.

Comment: Please provide a sample project to check.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the project files tab.  This does not correct the issue but allows me to see the source files.  [Project files tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl1I8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this and all I did was to right-click anywhere on the project sidebar, then click maven> Reload project.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers landing here, this worked for me:
click on `File -> Repair IDE` then on the bottom right corner:

- Step 1 - click on `Rescan Project Indexes`
- Step 2 - click on `Reopen Project`

N.B. I'm using IntelliJ 2022.2.3 (CE)